# How to get rid of Resource id #6?

Tags: php, mysql

why I cannot show the proper output in my code??

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(issued_qty) FROM issuance_tbl WHERE issuance_tbl.machine_no_id = '%$find%'");
echo $total;
```

I always get this error:

```
Resource id #6
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 5):

Because you have not read and understood the documentation for `mysql_query`. It returns a resource representing the result set, not the result itself (as the result may contain multiple rows).

If you are this early in your learning of PHP's MySQL support, **stop what you are doing now** and learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Answer (score 3):

use **mysql_fetch_array** to extract data:

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(issued_qty) FROM issuance_tbl WHERE issuance_tbl.machine_no_id = '%$find%'");
$data  = mysql_fetch_array($total);
echo $data[0];
```

By the way, Don't use **mysql_*** functions. they're deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Although `mysql_` functions are deprecated and that you should be switching to `mysqli` or `pdo`, I am going to try to answer your question.

That query as it seems to be successful, returned a resource with id #6.  To use that resource you could call `mysql_fetch_row` like follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(issued_qty) FROM issuance_tbl WHERE issuance_tbl.machine_no_id = '%$find%'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Then your total is at index 0 of $row array
$total = $row[0];
echo $total;
```